# Use REGEX to find line breaks within a wrapped content

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-lookarounds

The direct question: How can I use REGEX lookarounds to find instances of \r\n that occur between a set of characters (stand in open and closing tags), `"[` and `]"` with arbitrary characters and line breaks inside as well?

The situation:

I have a large database exported to tab or comma delineated text files that I'm trying to import into excel. The problem is that some of the cells come from text areas that contain line breaks, and are qualified by double quotes. Importing into excel these line breaks are treated as new rows. I cannot adjust how the file is exported. I data needs to be preserved, but the exact format doesn't, so I was planning on using some placeholder for the returns 
 or ~

Here's a generic illustration of the format of my data:

```
column1rowA    column2rowA    column3rowA    column4rowA
column1rowB    column2rowB   "column3rowB
3Bcont
3Bcont
3Bcont

"    column4rowB
column1rowC    column2rowC                   column4rowC
column1rowD    column2rowD   "column3rowD
3Dcont"    column4rowD
```

My thought has been to try to select and replace line breaks within the quotes using REGEX search and replace in Notepad++. To try and make is simpler I have tried adding a character to the double quotes to help indicate whether it is an opening or closing quote:

```
"[column3rowB
3Bcont
3Bcont
3Bcont

]"
```

I am new to REGEX. The progress I've made (which isn't much) is:

`(?<="[)` missing some sort of wildcard `\r\n(?=.*]")`

Every iteration I've tried has *also* included every line break between the first `"[` and last `]"`

I would also appreciate any other approaches that solve the underlying problem

Comment: Doesn't Excel already handle line breaks in values without any massaging?  I just made a CSV file and put some line breaks in a couple of the values, opened it in Excel, and it contained everything within the cells it was supposed to with no effort.  **Edit**: I re-ran the test using tabs as delimiters, and Excel got confused.  You might be able to solve your problem by replacing `\t` with `,`.

Comment: It seems like, in the end, you would need to preserve the line breaks that are in the data; in other words, you don't want to lose data, right? Try the suggestion from @rojo first, since that will handle them.

Comment: Can you even have multiple lines in a cell ?

Comment: Can you replace `(^|    )"` (four spaces) with `\1"\[` and `"($|    )` (four spaces also) with `\]"\1`. S/O's comments strip out the spare spacing, but the spaces for the regexes should be as marked.

Comment: Alternatively, you could probably replace `"([^"]*)"` with `"\[\1\]"` with `. matches newline` **checked**.

Comment: For whatever reason neither tab nor comma work. Getting the data imported is more important than the line breaks, I should have mentioned that in the OP (edited to reflect that).

Comment: You can replace linebreaks between quotes. But, this -> `column2rowD   "column3rowD` is not delimited between 2D and 3D. And other question(s): Do quotes denote a complete field ? If so, how are quotes in quoted fields escaped? Can fields be quoted with double _and/or_ single quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use some tool other than Notepad++, you can use this regex (see my working example on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/sV0nX6/1)):

```
(?!\n(([^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)\n
```

It uses a negative lookahead to find line breaks only when not followed by an even number of quotes. You could replace them with `<br>`, spaces, or whatever is appropriate.

**Breakdown:**

`(?! ... )` This is the negative lookahead, necessary because it's zero-width. Anything matched by it will still be available to match again.

`(([^"]*"){2})*` This is the other key piece. It ensures even-numbered pairs of non-quote characters followed by a quote.

`[^"]*$` This is ensuring that there are no more quotes from there until the end of the string.

**Caveat:**
I couldn't get it to work in Notepad++ because it always recognizes `$` as the end of a line, not the end of the entire string.

Answer (score 1):

Great answer from Brian. I added an option that would only consider real linebreaks (i.e. \n\r), which worked for my CSV file:

```
(?!\n|\r(([^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)\n|\r
```

Comment: First off, `\r\n` is not a "real line break", it is Windows line break. Second, even if it was valid, such minor differences should rather be an edit suggestion.